# How do you insure your gear?  Or do you?

Tags: recording, field-recording, insurance, travel, protect

I recently took a trip to Hawaii and decided to bring some of my recording gear with me to record some ambiances, whales and other things I don't get the chance to hear in Southern California.  I went to my insurance agent (with one of the big agencies) and inquired about getting a ryder on my policy to cover my gear when it's out of my house and on location.  I wrote a check and thought everything would be fine.  That is until I got home and found out they don't insure recording gear.  After many conversations, I was told that it was too "high risk" and they decided long ago not to insure recording gear.  They're looking into a broker to see if they can find anyone that will but so far no luck.

My question to you guys is, do you (and if so, how) insure your gear for additional coverage other than theft while in your home?

I've done multiple searches before and no luck.  Thanks in advance and love the forum!

Answer (score 3):

Lots of production mixers in and around LA seem to use Kat Wong at https://www.buymyinsurancenow.com/OnlinePrograms (aka insuremyequipment.com).

Comment: Great link @NoiseJockey, super useful!

Answer (score 1):

I insure all my gear, and it's covered even while overseas. I often travel with my sound equipment to places where theft is a reality. And a few years back my house burnt down and lost everything, so I know things happen.

I don't know what to suggest about your insurance as I don't know the U.S system, but there has got to be companies or policies that will insure you, even if it's pricier.  I find that smaller and more specialized insurance companies to be more lenient with policies. Whether they pay up or not is a different story.

You could maybe call up a gear house and ask how they handle their insurance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Don't know why I hadn't thought about calling a gear house.

Answer (score 1):

I have renter's insurance (which is about $300 a year), which covers my house (which I currently rent), everything in it (up to an amount that you specify to them), and anything that is with me on trips (as long as you have the proper documentation).

So, a little over a year ago, when a cab driver in NYC sped off with my gear in his trunk (a few custom mics, my portable PT rig (including my Mac Book Pro) a recorder, $500 worth of headphones, and a few other odds and ends), my insurance company (Geico at that point) paid up, and quickly.  Got an $8000 check in the mail about 3 weeks later.  The only hassle I had was getting the proper paperwork from NYPD.  The insurance company was extremely easy and surprisingly pleasant to deal with.

EDIT:

BTW, they don't cover anything that you accidentally lose or break, just stuff that's stolen from you...

Comment: Seeing a cab driver drive off with all your gear must be the worst feeling! 

Comment: I've got homeowners insurance as well but was looking for supplemental insurance for when I travel.

That sucks about your gear. I can't even imagine the sinking feeling you got seeing the cabbie drive away.